# How to manually assign products to categories in bulk, in opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, categories

I am using an extension to import products from csv file, So far the import has been successful and products seem to appear in the catalog. However, despite of category being updated in mysql table "oc_product_to_category".

I also tried using the below code to update categories in mysql directly but no luck. it looks like open-cart wants me to use admin interface for each and every product.

```
if (isset($data['product_category'])) {
  foreach ($data['product_category'] as $category_id) {
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category SET 
  product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', category_id = '" 
  (int)$category_id . "'");
  }
  }
```

The above code is updating mysql successfully but they are not being affected. 
is there something i am missing? or are there any other tables in open-cart that handles in assigning products to categories?

Comment: What is your opencart version ? You need to update in lot of tables like `product_to_category`, `product_to_store` etc, in order to make a product visible.

Comment: i am using opencart 2.1.0.1. I had no idea about product_to_store. i will try that out now. Thankyou

Comment: Hi, i tried updating `product_to_store` , `product_to_layout` and `product_to_category` but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you trying to map the products with categories or updating/creating the categories?

From the code, I can understand that you are trying to update the product - category mapping.

- Why don't you try in which table and in which code flow it is working in the admin panel?
- In general, mapping the product to the category is done through the
  above table. But does anything override the default behaviour?
- Any Modification files or custom tables?
- From where the product - category mapping is fetched?

It should give you an answer for sure.